# Get next collection date but take account of public holidays

Tags: php, date, search, calendar, days

I'm putting together a quick next collection date checker and could do with a little help!

Essentially, we always collect on Fridays but only on odd weeks of the year. The only exception to that would be if it was a week that contained a UK public/bank holiday - in those cases the collection would be on a Saturday.

Here's what I have so far -

```
$weekNumber = date("W");
$thisfriday = new DateTime();
$thisfriday->modify('this friday');
$nextfriday = new DateTime();
$nextfriday->modify('this friday +1 weeks');
if($weekNumber &1) {
echo $thisfriday->format('l d F');
} else {
echo $nextfriday->format('l d F');
}
```

Any tips on the bank holiday weeks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a custom php calendar, you should do by hand, creating a array of bank holidays, maybe this is helpful for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country .

In the official documentation of PHP there are a script to get the UK bank holydays per year (check here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php):

```
function calculateBankHolidays($yr) {

    $bankHols = Array();

    // New year's:
    switch ( date("w", strtotime("$yr-01-01 12:00:00")) ) {
        case 6:
            $bankHols[] = "$yr-01-03";
            break;
        case 0:
            $bankHols[] = "$yr-01-02";
            break;
        default:
            $bankHols[] = "$yr-01-01";
    }

    // Good friday:
    $bankHols[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "+".(easter_days($yr) - 2)." days", strtotime("$yr-03-21 12:00:00") ));

...
```

I think that one of the best approximation would be to use a **existing library** or using **PEAR** package (http://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays) and then you can do something like (change Germany to UK):

```
 <?php
require_once "Date/Holidays.php";
$germany = &Date_Holidays::factory('Germany', 2004, 'en_EN');
if (Date_Holidays::isError($germany)) {
    die('Factory was unable to produce driver-object');
}
$easter = &$germany->getHoliday('easter', 'de_DE');
if (!Date_Holidays::isError($easter)) {
    print_r($easter->toArray());
}
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: For the first option which is quicker to implement, first build an array of bank hols and check next Friday doesn't fall next year: `$bankhols = calculateBankHolidays($thisfriday->format('Y')); if($thisfriday->format('Y') != $nextfriday->format('Y')) { $bankhols = array_merge($bankhols, calculateBankHolidays($nextfriday->format('Y')) }`
Then add the condition:
`if ($weeknumber &1 && array_search($thisfriday->format('Y-m-d'),$bankhols)!==false) {...`
You may need to add another `else` to check if both Fridays were BH.